# Function not receiving correct inputs

Tags: php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Register</title>
    <style>
        #reg_form {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            /*max-width: 50vw;*/
            min-height: 100vh;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="register.php" method='post' id="reg_form">
        <input type="text" name="reg_fname" required placeholder="John">
        <input type="text" name="reg_lname" required placeholder="Doe">
        <input type="email" name="reg_email" required placeholder="example@gmail.com">
        <input type="email" name="reg_email2" required placeholder="example@gmail.com">
        <input type="password" name="reg_password" required>
        <input type="password" name="reg_password2" required>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="register_button">
    </form>

    <?php
        $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'social');

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo 'Connection error: '.mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        $fname = '';
        $lname = '';
        $email = '';
        $email2 = '';
        $password = '';
        $password2 = '';
        $date = '';
        $error_array = '';

        if (isset($_POST['register_button'])) {
            beautify($fname, 'reg_fname'); // fname
            beautify($lname, 'reg_lname'); // lname

            beautify($email, 'reg_email'); //email
            beautify($email2, 'reg_email2'); //email2

            $password = strip_tags($_POST['reg_password']); // password
            $password2 = strip_tags($_POST['reg_password2']); // password2

            $date = date('Y-m-d');

            if ($email == $email2) {

            } else {
                echo "Emails don't match";
            }
        }

        function beautify($var_name, $input_name) {
            $var_name = strip_tags($_POST[$input_name]);
            $var_name = str_replace(' ', '', $var_name);
            $var_name = ucfirst(strtolower($input_name));
        }

    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm suspecting the `beautify` function is not working as expected. Because I'm not getting the echo statement if the emails don't match. I'm expecting to get the echo statement if the emails don't match. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Your function never returns any values so it is essentially doing nothing at all really.

Comment: Your `beautify` function does not return a modified value, nor does it modify the original one, so it is basically pointless.

Comment: And stop applying stuff like strip_tags or similar to _passwords_, for crying out loud! Can you not realize, what a bad idea that is?

Comment: How  do I make it so that the function alters the original variable?

Comment: Two ways to do that: Pass the parameter by reference (_not_ the recommendable option here), or make the function _return_ the changed value, and assign it to the variable again in the place where you call the function.

Comment: `return ucfirst(strtolower(str_replace(' ', '',strip_tags($_POST[$input_name]))));` and call it using `$fname = beautify('reg_fname');`. Changed the function to only require the form field name `beautify($input_name)`.

Comment: how  about declaring `var_name` as GLOBAL at the start of the function? Will that make a reference to the global variable that will be passed when calling the function?

Comment: NO! Say no to GLOBALs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the function to only require the name of the form input field and have it return the "beautified" value to the caller.

```
function beautify($input_value) {
    return ucfirst(strtolower(str_replace(' ', '',strip_tags($input_value))));
}
```

Call it using `$fname = beautify($_POST['reg_fname']);` etc for each of your form input fields.

Comment: The function doesn't "clean" values. It beautifies them

Comment: Fair enough, changed the wording :)

Comment: Curious why the reliance on using $_POST inside the function... seems like it makes it really dependent on post beautifying only. I would suggest instead passing the actual value via: `$fname = beautify( $_POST['reg_fname'] );` then inside the function it just adjusts that value and spits it back out.

Comment: I modified the answer to include your suggestion @IncredibleHat .... hopefully the OP will see it.

Answer (score -1):

You `beautify` function does not return any values:

```
function beautify($input_name) {
   $name= strip_tags($_POST[$input_name]);
   $name= str_replace(' ', '', $name);
   return ucfirst(strtolower($name));
}
```

and call it as:

```
$fname = beautify('reg_fname');
```

In short the function will be:

```
function beautify($input_name) {
   return ucfirst(strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', strip_tags($_POST[$input_name]))));
}
```